# Error when converting from pyspark RDD to DataFrame: Cannot infer schema of type 'unicode'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have loaded a CSV file into RDD format using sc.textFile

```
gExp = sc.textFile("/mnt/%s/RNA-Seq/GSE10846_Gene_Expression_Data.csv" % MOUNT_NAME)
```

I want to convert this to a Spark DataFrame

```
header = gExp.take(1) 
data = gExp.filter(lambda row : row != header).toDF(header)
```

Here, I am receiving an error:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:

Comment: And that answer is definitely not a general answer for 'unicode' error.